# Attach multiple files in nodejs expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

i want to send response some files with express API
using res.attachment only can attach one file, any idea? (except using zip)

Comment: Just use zip... What website have you used before that returns multiple files in one response without using some archive format?

Comment: Consider using [multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.